# Root Element missing when using EmbeddedResource option of XmlProvider

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am trying to use XmlProvider loading the sample from an embedded resource like follows where the name of the assembly is NMapDotNet and the same of the file is Sample.xml.

```ml
type ScanResult = XmlProvider<EmbeddedResource="NMapDotNet, Sample.xml">
```

The error that is returned is `error FS3033: The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.XmlProvider' reported an error: The provided sample is neither a file, nor a well-formed XML: Root element is missing.`

This approach works if I use `XmlProvider<"Sample.xml">` instead so it seems something is wrong with the declaration statement.  Am I misinterpreting the [documentation](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-xmlprovider.html)?

**Update (9/9)**

The project file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>NMapDotNet</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Xml.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Types.fs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Sample.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="CipherScanResult.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Nmap.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="fsharp.data" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you able to share the relevant bit from your `.fsproj`? JsonProvider example here: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.Toolbox/blob/master/src/FSharp.Data.Toolbox.Twitter/Twitter.fs

Comment: Try to remove the comma after the space, within the string. I don't know if that will help, but won't be surprised if it does.

Comment: @BentTranberg - Did you mean "the space after the comma"? Because the example that drkmtr posted has a comma but no space...

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry about that. I'm thinking (apart from thinking backwards) that the parser of that string perhaps doesn't take into account such an obvious thing as stripping spaces. I would guess it does, but it's worth a try still.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but continuation.
I just wonder if EmbeddedResource worked at all, because looking onto source code:

1) it seems that expected assembly, mentioned in EmbeddedResource, should exist at designTime - so, before you compile a project where you use XmlProvider (please correct me if my understanding is wrong). So you cannot include Sample.xml as resource into current project where you use XmlProvider.

2) but when I create another project with Sample.xml - it gives another error: 
The operation 'reading manifest resource %s' on item 'flow2.test.xml' should not be called on provided type, member or parameter of type 'ProviderImplementation.ProvidedTypes.TargetAssembly'

This is raised [here at GetManifestResourceStream](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/2dc537153e38bc1c20c858e934fb007f64db0dc9/src/CommonProviderImplementation/Helpers.fs#L171)

3) so I went to FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK
and found a [commented code](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK/blob/master/src/ProvidedTypes.fs#L8045) that seems to be not completed:

```ml
        override x.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName:string) =
            //let r = getReader().ILModuleDef.Resources.Entries |> Seq.find (fun r -> r.Name = resourceName)
            //match r.Location with
            //| ILResourceLocation.Local f -> new MemoryStream(f()) :> Stream
            //| _ -> 
            notRequired x "reading manifest resource %s" resourceName
```

Question is then at what version of ProvidedTypes.fs did it work at all?

Comment: It looks like that code is not commented out in the latest version of the file, and I was able to get the `EmbeddedResource` parameter to work. Please see my answer if you're still trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

YMMV, but I was having trouble trying to get the EmbeddedResource option to work and my finding was that I had to specify the assembly name, followed by the full embedded resource path to the file.

So assuming my assembly is named `My.Assembly` and the file `Sample.xml` is in a folder named `Samples`, it would be:

```
EmbeddedResoucre = "My.Assembly, My.Assembly.Samples.Sample.xml"
```

I'm using FSharp.Data 3.3.3, so this may differ from earlier versions.